# What's the correct sign regarding Hom complexes and shifts?

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a complex and $K$ be a module which is viewed as a complex concentrated in degree 0. I'm wondering what sign should a canonical map $\Phi\colon\text{Hom}(M, K)[a-b]\to \text{Hom}(M[b], K[a])$ impose on $f\in\text{Hom}(M^n, K)$.

As shown at the bottom of [Sign rules -- The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FNG), the sign $(-1)^{nb}$ is a natural choice.

However, if we decompose $\Phi$ into two maps $\text{Hom}(M, K)[a-b]\to \text{Hom}(M, K[a])[-b]\to \text{Hom}(M[b], K[a])$, the same reasoning shows that the first map gives no sign and the second one gives a sign of $(-1)^{(n+a)b}$.

If I haven't got anything wrong, there seems to be a difference of signs when calculating in different ways. Then which one would be the correct sign?

Comment: I don’t understand. If you know $a-b$, how do you determine $b$ in order to use this sign convention?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I think most of the time I know $a$ and $b$, and then use this sign convention by applying $\Phi^{-1}$.